# Vorpal - how to execute a command with a prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vorpal.js

I'm currently using a 3rd party application that uses Vorpal in REPL mode. I'm trying to automate some deployment configuration for use in my project using the `exec` function in Vorpal. Everything is working until there is a prompt. At that point, my execution hangs and I'm not able to progress until I do some manually steps (which is not what I want).

I looked at the docs, but there are no mentions of any trick to do that. I would like to avoid having to change the already existing code in-depth, but I'll do it if required to use options.

Here is a sample of my code:
https://gist.github.com/gretro/b67aa364967c3fa2c82279b7e4236c2e

Is there anything I missed or a trick that can be used to do what I need to do?

Comment: What version of node are you using? There was a `readline` bug that was fixed recently (in node v8.x) that was causing a similar issue for npm.

Comment: I'm using Node 6.9.5. I'll try upgrading, although the 3rd party app is using Node 6.5.0 in their Docker image.

Comment: If you're using node v6.x, then the bug I was referring to doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 0):

The code below might help, the exec command can either be used to to invoke the vorpal command with or without command line arguments, and if without then the username and password are prompted for. Is this what you were after?

```
    /*jshint esversion: 6 */
    const vorpal         = require('vorpal')();
    vorpal
        .delimiter('vorpal$')
        .command('logon [uname] [pwd]', 'logs you on.')
            .action(function(args, callback) {        
                var the_username = "";
                var the_password = "";

                if (args.uname !== undefined) {
                    the_username = args.uname;
                    the_password = args.pwd;
                    console.log("The username was: "+the_username);
                    console.log("The password was: "+the_password);
                } else {
                    let questions = [
                        {
                            type: 'input',
                            name: 'username',
                            message: 'Enter username: '    
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'password',
                            name: 'password',
                            message: 'Enter password: '    
                        }
                    ];

                    this.prompt(questions, function (answers){
                        the_username = answers.username;
                        the_password = answers.password;
                        console.log("The prompted username was: "+the_username);
                        console.log("The prompted password was: "+the_password);    
                    });
                }
            });
    vorpal.show();
    // Uncomment the appropriate exec command, the one with arguments, 
    // or the one that prompts for the username/password.
    // vorpal.exec('logon auser apassword');
    vorpal.exec('logon');
```

The execution looks like this:

```
vorpal$
The username was: auser
The password was: apassword
```

Or like this:

```
vorpal$
Enter username: fdfss
Enter password: ******
The prompted username was: fdfss
The prompted password was: fdfsdf
```